# How to separate custom post type categories to post categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to separate the category lists for a specific post type "announcement" from the post categories.

I want my announcement post type to have its own category list and not mix with the post category list

Here's my code

```
function announcement_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'announcement',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Announcements' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'announcement' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Announcements' ),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Announcements' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Announcement' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'New Announcement' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'New Announcement' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Announcements' ),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'Not Found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not Found in Trash' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'announcement'),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields')
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy(  
    'announcement_type',  
    'announcement',  // this is the custom post type(s) I want to use this taxonomy for
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => false,  
            'label' => 'News Types',  
            'query_var' => true,  
            'rewrite' => true  
        )  
    );  
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'announcement');
}
add_action('init', 'announcement_post_types');
```

Answer (score 1):

If this code is working, this is what links the regular categories to the announcement post type:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'announcement');
```

We need to exchange it with the new taxonomy you created and registered, so exchange it with this:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('announcement_type', 'announcement');
```

Let me know if this did the trick for you, there might be more issues here, but this might also be enough.

Comment: Thanks dude, I just updated my code and it works for me now I removed the register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'announcement');

Comment: glad i could help!

Comment: @JosephLariosa - i am not sure if deleting this is ok. Quote from documentation: ```Better be safe than sorry when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use register_taxonomy_for_object_type() right after the function to interconnect them. Else you could run into minetraps where the post type isn't attached inside filter callback that run during parse_request or pre_get_posts.``` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I removed the `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'announcement');` and changed into this

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' =>_x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Announcement Category' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Announcement Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Announcement Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Announcement Category' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Announcement categories' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used categories' )
        );
    register_taxonomy(  
    'announcement_type',  
    'announcement',  // this is the custom post type(s) I want to use this taxonomy for
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => false,  
            'label' => 'News Types',  
            'query_var' => true,  
            'label' => __('Announcement Category'),
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'rewrite' => true  
        )  
    );
```

It works for me now,

If you have better answer for this please share :) I want to make this code shorter.

Comment: I am not sure if deleting this is ok. Quote from documentation: ```Better be safe than sorry when registering custom taxonomies for custom post types. Use register_taxonomy_for_object_type() right after the function to interconnect them. Else you could run into minetraps where the post type isn't attached inside filter callback that run during parse_request or pre_get_posts.``` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy